# Resetting scroll bar in JavaFX on button click

Tags: javafx-2

I have used two scroll bars for controlling brightness and contrast on image after the use i want to reset the scroll bars to their initial value with a button click

I am not getting any links for that to reset scroll bars on button clicks in JavaFX?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question somewhat unclear. Need explanation of "not getting any links". Some sample code would be helpful. Based on an assumption, try this:

```
final ScrollBar scrollBar = new ScrollBar();

Button btn = new Button("Reset");
btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
        scrollBar.setValue(scrollBar.getMin());
        // Or if you have stored initial value somewhere use it
        scrollBar.setValue(myInitialValue);
    }
});
```

Comment: Oh i missed to use it I was confused with setValue function and looking for some function to scroll the cursor to initial state Thanks, a lot. I appreciate your help. I will be thankfull if you can help me with one more problem:: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17785568/memory-issue-in-javafx-multiple-screen-desktop-applicaton